# Why doesn't chrome save my username on this site?

Tags: google-chrome, passwords

I use Chrome as my password manager, and it's usually pretty good at figuring out when I've put in some credentials (it asks me to save the username/password when I log in, and gives me the option to click save/update). However, when I log into one of my banks' online portals (https://ib.unibank.com.au/IB/SignOn/Login.aspx) Chrome seems to struggle;

[image]

It successfully recognises and saves the password, but doesn't store the member number. If I click on the Member Number text field it correctly identifies that it hasn't stored a username:

[image]

At this point I would normally just put in my member number, login, and chrome would prompt me to link the username to the password, but instead, this doesn't happen. It just never saves the username, meaning I have to type it in every time.

This is different to the behaviour I've encountered on *all* other websites, including other financial institutions, so I don't think it's a safety feature. What's causing this, and what's the work-around (other than remembering my member number)?

Comment: It's related to the id or name of the username element on html source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome has this strange behavior for reasons that I have never been able to figure out. Saving Login Credentials to Chrome means they are stored in your Google account to which you are logged into the browser. But sometimes, only the password get saved and username remains blank. I have seen this happen mostly when I forget the password

**An effective workaround:**

You can see that there is no username saved for me for this particular website (blurred out). When I go to `chrome://settings/passwords`, I can only see the password and username remains blank:

[image]

So, when I visit that website and try to login, my password fills up automatically while I have to enter username manually each time.

Clicking the 'three dots' (shown in the above figure) doesn't help you either in editing the password or the username. That means, you can just view the password and username at most. For editing the credentials (here the Username field):

- Go to Google Password Manager [by clicking here](https://passwords.google.com).
- Scroll down and you will see all the websites in which you've opted for saving password.
- Click the website that you are having problem with. In the next page you're required to enter your google password. Enter it in the provided box and 'Sign in'.
- You'll see a page like this:

[image]

- Click on 'Edit' and you will see the textboxes for editing your credentials. Just enter your Username (in your case **Member Number**) and click 'Save':

[image]

That's it. Next time you visit that webpage, you will have your **Member Number** filled in the Username field.

I hope this helps. Tell me how it does :)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this very behavior in Chrome on other websites.  I believe the reason behind this is that Chrome is looking for a username and password to save, but not finding a username.  If you look at the source of your login page, "Member Number" is limited to a *numeric* text field.  I think Chrome does not associate a numerically limited field as a proper username and therefore, doesnt save that data.  I have seen this numeric text field issue occur on other websites I use.

I am not 100% positive this is the case, but the evidence seems to point to it being valid.  Maybe someone else can confirm.

Comment: I guess it isn't exactly due to numeric text field since I have seen chrome behaving this way many a times when the input field is not numeric as well.